# Spyder code editing area can not be automatically completed after the installation of tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, spyder

Spyder code editing area can not be automatically completed after the installation of tensorflow, I have re-installed again and found the same problem.
the installation of a tensorflow lose the function of padding. My environment is win10, anaconda3.5, python3.6.3, tensorflow1.4

Comment: You need to describe the question more if you would like somebody to be able to reproduce the problem in a way that they can provide an answer to you.

Comment: Now that I have to use a temporary alternative, I installed anaconda version without an installed tensorflow in anaconda's envs. I hope this question can be answered, thank you very much! !

Comment: @Heikki Thank you for your attention, the problem is such a small bug, installed tensorflow, my spyder code editing area can not use the all lib function autocomplement such as opencv, numpy, but in IPython it can.

Comment: If you think that the question has no common interest, and there is no need to come back to the question, please remove the question.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a known bug, but unfortunately we don't know how to fix it.